# Screen freezes every 1-7 days

Tags: drivers, gpu, crash, proprietary-drivers

One of the last error messages that I could find on `journalctl`:

```
Jan 25 12:10:43 G4560 kernel: [drm] GPU recovery disabled.
Jan 25 12:10:43 G4560 kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Process information: process chrome pid 602559 thread chrome:cs0 pid 602>
Jan 25 12:10:43 G4560 kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring gfx timeout, signaled seq=57075935, emitted seq=57075937

Jan 18 22:52:09 G4560 kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Process information: process Xorg pid 1650376 thread Xorg:cs0 pid 1650377
Jan 18 22:52:09 G4560 kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring gfx timeout, signaled seq=21573521, emitted seq=21573523
```

sometimes no error on log, just hang and I have to press reset button.

I'm using this GPU on Ubuntu 20.04 64-bit:

```
Graphics:  Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Oland [Radeon HD 8570 / R7 240/340 / Radeon 520 OEM] driver: amdgpu 
v: 5.6.0.20.20 
Display: server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: amdgpu,ati unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa resolution: 3840x2160~30Hz 
OpenGL: renderer: AMD Radeon HD 8500 Series (OLAND DRM 3.37.0 5.4.0-51-lowlatency LLVM 10.0.0) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.5 

$ GPU=$(lspci | grep VGA | cut -d ":" -f3);RAM=$(cardid=$(lspci | grep VGA |cut -d " " -f1);lspci -v -s $cardid | grep " prefetchable"| cut -d "=" -f2);echo $GPU $RAM

Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland [Radeon HD 8570 / R7 240/340 / Radeon 520 OEM] 256M]
```

back then it's about a week then hangs, lately it's been 1-3 days running well then hangs, there's some artifact on screen too before hangs.

I've done memtest86+ but found noproblem with the RAM, the VGA have dedicated ram.

Is it faulty hardware? since I bought this VGA card cheap back then when my past IGP on intel processor+motherboard is faulty.

What should be done to make this happening less often '__')